# Regular expression multi-line replacement in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to search and replace a block of text which contains new line characters.

In the example below when the DOTALL flag is specified, findall behaves as expected and `'.'` matches any character including a newline.
But when calling sub, the DOTALL flag doesn't seem to do anything and no matches are found. I just want to confirm that I can't use '.' with sub to replace text that contains new line characters or if I'm not calling the function correctly.

#### Code

```
import re
text = """
some example text...
START
bla bla
bla bla
END
"""
print 'this works:', re.findall('START.*END', text, re.DOTALL)
print 'this fails:', re.sub('START.*END', 'NEWTEXT', text, re.DOTALL)
```

#### Output

```
this works: ['START\nbla bla\nbla bla\nEND']
this fails:
some example text...
START
bla bla
bla bla
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but you have to specify `flags=` in [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) (the docs uses it).

```
print 'this works:', re.sub('START.*END', 'NEWTEXT', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

It might be because of the optional `count` argument.

EDIT:

I think that's because of the `count` argument after all, since this works as well:

```
print 'this works:', re.sub('START.*END', 'NEWTEXT', text, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

`0` meaning replacing all.

Comment: print 'this works:', re.sub('START.*END', 'NEWTEXT', text, 0, re.DOTALL) #also works

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh Yes, I was just testing this over